# Objects are not saved into SQL Lite even though it says it was saved [RestKit ManagedObjectContext]

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, nsmanagedobjectcontext

So I am having a very frustrating problem... I am fetching objects from my Django server using Restkit and the mapping is done successfully. That is fine! Now, I am trying to get that object from my SQLLite DB and change that object and save it back. For example:

```
    _managedObjectContext = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext;


    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"User"];
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"identifier == 3"];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"identifier" ascending:NO];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[descriptor];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController2 = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                        managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    BOOL fetchSuccessful = [fetchedResultsController2 performFetch:&error];
    if (! fetchSuccessful) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }

    PokaUser* user = [[fetchedResultsController2 fetchedObjects]objectAtIndex:0];
    user.firstName = @"NewFirstName";
    BOOL hasSaved = [user.managedObjectContext save:&error];
    NSLog(@"INFO:{%s} CoreData has Saved: %@ (%d)\nerror:%@ | %@ | %@", __FUNCTION__, (hasSaved) ? @"YES" : @"NO", hasSaved, error, [error userInfo],[error localizedDescription]);
```

I get the following log:

**CoreData has Saved: YES (1)
error:(null) | (null) | (null)**

Now, if I close my app, and REOPEN it, (or even go check the Sqllite.db myself), the changes were NOT saved. I keep getting the very first firstname.

Here is how I created my ManagedObjectContext:

```
[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];
NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Maindb.sqlite"];

NSString *seedPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Maindb" ofType:@"sqlite"];
NSError *error;
NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:seedPath withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];
NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);
```

Any ideas?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It is necessary to call the savePersistentStore method of managed ObjectStore: [managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext save:&error]; [managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext saveToPersistentStore:&error];

Comment: It's is the answer. But personally, RestKit wrapped too many things together. And actually not so efficient for CoreData Programming.